# Visual Studio 2010 builds Console Application only in x86 target

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86, console-application, default, target-platform

I assume that many would mark this question as duplicate, but let me explain what kind of problem I'm facing right now.

I've just noticed that Console Application in solution has `x86` target option, though everything else, e.g. libraries and dependent web site has `AnyCPU` target.

I've googled other question regarging Configuration Manager and adding new configuration `AnyCPU` for my Console Application, but here is the problem. I can't create new `AnyCPU` configuration as I get error, that it's already created:

[image]

And here is error creating new configuration with `AnyCPU` target:

[image]

I just don't get it why I can't create this configuration, it isn't listed in dropdown selector for my project.

There is another place where target configuration might be changed, it's project properties' build tab:

[image]

and I've set `AnyCPU` value in platform target, but platform is still `x86`.

The only way to change platform itself is editing csproj directly:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And here we come to my questions:
 What's the idea to place target property in two different properties?
 Why can't I select AnyCPU for console applications by default? There was opinion that Visual Studio team made this intentionally.
 And what possible issues might occur if I change target platform by editing csproj file?